# Cross-reference Distance chart in SQL Server 2008 or Excel?

Tags: sql-server, excel, charts, grid, distance

I would like to cross-reference construct a distance chart similar to the one [here (example is a road-distance cross-reference chart)](http://www.servasaustralia.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=18&Itemid=32) and, ideally, store the data in SQL Server 2008 (preferably the Express version). It needs these properties / abilities

- Every column has a corresponding row with the same name (ie. not misspelled like my example).
- Changing the value at one Row-Column intersection would update the mirror intersection (Column-Row) or the mirror data could be ignored.
- The distance-values would need to be end-user editable.
- The end-user would need to be able to add, delete or rename a column/row pair.
- The end-user needs to be able to sort the columns and have the rows move automatically.
- There could be hundreds of pairs.
- a look-up query needs to find a distance given a start & destination (Row & Column)

The distance chart is reasonably straightforward to implement in Excel. Considering this, am I better off...

- Using Excel as the user editing UI and then updating an SQL 'thing' with the new data?
- Using Excel as the data-source even if it means performance issues with querying the data?
- Using an as-yet undiscovered stroke of genius detailed here in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure looks like an Excel application to me, start to end. (heh)

I can't imagine your users typing enough data in to make performance an issue. Excel will only take 32757 rows by ditto columns. If that's enough, I'd say you're golden.

Comment: So, far I think you're right. I'd prefer a SQL database solution but I think I'm just wish square wheels would roll there.

Comment: BTW Excel 2003 does 65536 rows x 256 columns. 2 bytes x 1 byte.